# Save history partitions in Analysis Services measure group

Tags: ssas, cube

We have a multidimensional cube, with a stock on hand measure group, partitioned by year. The underlying table has 1.5 billion rows in it, and effectively equals around 275 million rows per partition.

Every night we do a process full on the entire SSAS database, and of course all these history partitions (like SOH 2011, SOH 2012 etc) process all over again, even though the data never changes.

I would like to know if there is a way of still executing a process full of the SSAS database , but preserving the data in those history partitions so that they do not get processed.

Update: In reply to one of the comments, about just processing the latest measure group partitions. Of course that is an option, and what that implies is that you are going to create a set of customised jobs / steps to process Dimensions, and then certain measure group partitions. This is more challenging to maintain, and also you have to be as smart as the SSAS engine to decide on parallel processing options etc.

My ideal solution would be to somehow mark those partitions as not needing processing, or restore the processed partitions from a previous process.

Comment: Can you provide examples on what you've attempted?

Comment: Why don't you process only the latest partitions instead of process full?